# After the messaging session is routed to an agent, the status remains as "Waiting"

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel, queue, whatsapp

I created a queue for routing the messaging sessions, but when the session is directed to an agent the status remains as "Waiting" making it impossible for the agent to view and interact with the chat.

[image]

[image]

Has anyone encountered this error and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caught by a flow that monitored the session status. After correcting the flow the behavior normalized.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can you please explain what you corrected in the flow?